# Is there any way to change the origin of the coordinate system in Python Imaging Library?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to create an image using PIL's Image module which has an origin of (0,0) in the bottom-left corner. PIL defaults to the origin being in the top-left, and as far as I can tell there isn't a way to change it.

Comment: You could subclass `Image` then provide functions to convert between the two coordinate systems.

Comment: Alternatively you could flip the image with `transpose`, manipulate it with the coordinates you "expect", but just remember to flip it back before displaying/saving.  But since this will undoubtedly lead to confusion, I'd consider jonrsharpe's suggestion first.